# Find entire function f such that $|f(z)|\leq k |z|^a$ , $k>0$, $a \in (1,2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find entire function f such that $|f(z)|\leq k |z|^a$ , $k>0$, $a \in (1,2)$

My idea:
$| \frac{f(z)}{z^a}| \leq k$
thus it is constant, so
$f(z) = cz^a $.
But $\frac{f(z)}{z^a} $ is not defined at $z=0$ so it is not entire function.

Comment: Hint: $f(0)=0$ and $\frac {f(z)} z$ becomes a bounded entire function if you define it as $f'(0)$ when $z=0$.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but i wasn't sure. thank you